# UserId not coming up in GA4 anymore (it did in UA)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

I have been tracking through GTM the visits to my pages while reporting a userId that my platform is pushing everytime the page loads within the tag. To do so, I followed the regular procedure of adding the userId as a custom dimension in the datalayer in GTM and it worked beautifully.

Ever since transitioning to GA4, I can't seem to retrieve this dimension anymore, even though I can see it is collected in the debugger whenever I visit a page. In any report, this dimensions comes up as (not set). It works correctly for another dimension called companyId.

any idea where it might come from ? [image]
The screenshot comes from the debugger, in the payload of my pageview custom event.

Comment: if this dimension is a customised dimension you have to create this variable in GTM, and define how you are going to set the value, from JS , Customised JS function (then you should define this variable and function in GTM).  Managing GTM is different in GA4 and UA, since you have not explained in details we cannot help more

Answer (score 1):

The way of manage the users at GA4 if fully different and much more "automagic"
Follow this guide in order to implement it https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-4-user-id
i think is the more complete one
And good luck ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).